# ./startFabric error - endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Worked fine the past, but suddenly getting this error:

```
➜  fabric-dev-servers sh startFabric.sh
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'startFabric.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv11
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
Stopping peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Stopping orderer.example.com    ... done
Stopping ca.org1.example.com    ... done
Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Removing couchdb                ... done
Removing orderer.example.com    ... done
Removing ca.org1.example.com    ... done
Removing network composer_default
Creating network "composer_default" with the default driver
Creating couchdb             ... done
Creating orderer.example.com ... done
Creating ca.org1.example.com ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
sleeping for 15 seconds to wait for fabric to complete start up
2018-07-26 14:55:26.080 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 14:55:26.080 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-26 14:55:26.082 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-07-26 14:55:26.085 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 004 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 14:55:26.085 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 005 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-26 14:55:26.085 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 006 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 14:55:26.085 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 007 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-26 14:55:26.085 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 008 Sign: plaintext: 0AA2060A074F7267314D53501296062D...6D706F736572436F6E736F727469756D
2018-07-26 14:55:26.085 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: 7BF1F117E07245C8759414A4D2BCB5C92CAC6B18D1E7BC1907188268080D5A63
2018-07-26 14:55:26.086 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00a Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 14:55:26.086 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00b Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-26 14:55:26.086 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00c Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 14:55:26.086 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00d Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-26 14:55:26.086 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00e Sign: plaintext: 0ADF060A1B08021A0608DEC1E7DA0522...91720051DE341491FFB2F20CBD0DE43F
2018-07-26 14:55:26.086 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00f Sign: digest: C40D32772EA507D8C0F5CBED2A14F596581338CDBDDFD4832BC4ACC215B58A5B
2018-07-26 14:55:26.112 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 010 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 14:55:26.112 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 011 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-26 14:55:26.112 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 012 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 14:55:26.112 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 013 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-26 14:55:26.112 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 014 Sign: plaintext: 0ADF060A1B08021A0608DEC1E7DA0522...9118719E23A812080A021A0012021A00
2018-07-26 14:55:26.112 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 015 Sign: digest: BF868154BF20E975A0456752C6D6FD46548B6B7C721FAE11EF6396B7D729B334
2018-07-26 14:55:26.113 UTC [channelCmd] readBlock -> DEBU 016 Got status: &{NOT_FOUND}
2018-07-26 14:55:26.113 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 017 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 14:55:26.113 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 018 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-26 14:55:26.116 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 019 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-07-26 14:55:26.319 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 01a Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 14:55:26.319 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 01b Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-26 14:55:26.319 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 01c Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 14:55:26.319 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 01d Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-26 14:55:26.319 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 01e Sign: plaintext: 0ADF060A1B08021A0608DEC1E7DA0522...C7C65F59F23412080A021A0012021A00
2018-07-26 14:55:26.319 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 01f Sign: digest: 869D72289AFE243A3F79BB22ECEAFAE67495765F7D616116403FA23FC7CD0DFF
2018-07-26 14:55:26.323 UTC [channelCmd] readBlock -> DEBU 020 Received block: 0
2018-07-26 14:55:26.323 UTC [main] main -> INFO 021 Exiting.....
2018-07-26 14:55:26.527 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 14:55:26.527 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-07-26 14:55:26.528 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 003 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.18.0.5:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 <nil>}
2018-07-26 14:55:27.531 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 004 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.18.0.5:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 <nil>}
2018-07-26 14:55:29.238 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 005 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.18.0.5:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051 <nil>}
Error: Error getting endorser client channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
Usage:
  peer channel join [flags]

Flags:
  -b, --blockpath string   Path to file containing genesis block

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
  -v, --version                             Display current version of fabric peer server
```

Seems to be an issue with CouchDB?

```
➜  fabric-dev-servers docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
dfaa16cbbe10        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0      "peer node start"        21 seconds ago      Up 20 seconds       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
e9d6d573fca2        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0   "orderer"                22 seconds ago      Up 21 seconds       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
99b686628958        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   22 seconds ago      Up 21 seconds       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com
➜  fabric-dev-servers docker logs dfaa16cbbe10
2018-07-26 15:51:49.887 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 15:51:49.887 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 002 Starting peer:
 Version: 1.1.0
 Go version: go1.9.2
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Experimental features: false
 Chaincode:
  Base Image Version: 0.4.6
  Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
2018-07-26 15:51:49.887 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 003 Returning existing local MSP
2018-07-26 15:51:49.887 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 004 Initializing ledger mgmt
2018-07-26 15:51:49.887 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 005 Initializing ledger provider
2018-07-26 15:51:49.887 UTC [kvledger.util] CreateDirIfMissing -> DEBU 006 CreateDirIfMissing [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/ledgerProvider/]
2018-07-26 15:51:49.887 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 007 Before creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/ledgerProvider/] does not exist
2018-07-26 15:51:49.888 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 008 After creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/ledgerProvider/] exists
2018-07-26 15:51:49.891 UTC [kvledger.util] CreateDirIfMissing -> DEBU 009 CreateDirIfMissing [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/index/]
2018-07-26 15:51:49.891 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 00a Before creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/index/] does not exist
2018-07-26 15:51:49.891 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 00b After creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/index/] exists
2018-07-26 15:51:49.895 UTC [kvledger.util] CreateDirIfMissing -> DEBU 00c CreateDirIfMissing [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/pvtdataStore/]
2018-07-26 15:51:49.895 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 00d Before creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/pvtdataStore/] does not exist
2018-07-26 15:51:49.895 UTC [kvledger.util] logDirStatus -> DEBU 00e After creating dir - [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/pvtdataStore/] exists
2018-07-26 15:51:49.898 UTC [statecouchdb] NewVersionedDBProvider -> DEBU 00f constructing CouchDB VersionedDBProvider
2018-07-26 15:51:49.899 UTC [couchdb] CreateConnectionDefinition -> DEBU 010 Entering CreateConnectionDefinition()
2018-07-26 15:51:49.899 UTC [couchdb] CreateConnectionDefinition -> DEBU 011 Created database configuration  URL=[http://couchdb:5984]
2018-07-26 15:51:49.899 UTC [couchdb] CreateConnectionDefinition -> DEBU 012 Exiting CreateConnectionDefinition()
2018-07-26 15:51:49.899 UTC [couchdb] VerifyCouchConfig -> DEBU 013 Entering VerifyCouchConfig()
2018-07-26 15:51:49.899 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 014 Entering handleRequest()  method=GET  url=http://couchdb:5984/
2018-07-26 15:51:49.899 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 015 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  |
2018-07-26 15:51:49.900 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 016 Retrying couchdb request in 125ms. Attempt:1  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 172.26.0.2:5984: getsockopt: connection refused
2018-07-26 15:51:50.027 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 017 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  |
2018-07-26 15:51:50.028 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 018 Retrying couchdb request in 250ms. Attempt:2  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 172.26.0.2:5984: getsockopt: connection refused
2018-07-26 15:51:50.278 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 019 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  |
2018-07-26 15:51:50.279 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 01a Retrying couchdb request in 500ms. Attempt:3  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 172.26.0.2:5984: getsockopt: connection refused
2018-07-26 15:51:50.780 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 01b HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  |
2018-07-26 15:51:50.781 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 01c Retrying couchdb request in 1s. Attempt:4  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 172.26.0.2:5984: getsockopt: connection refused
2018-07-26 15:51:51.781 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 01d HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  |
2018-07-26 15:51:51.783 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 01e Retrying couchdb request in 2s. Attempt:5  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 172.26.0.2:5984: getsockopt: connection refused
2018-07-26 15:51:53.785 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 01f HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  |
2018-07-26 15:51:53.793 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 020 Retrying couchdb request in 4s. Attempt:6  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-26 15:51:57.794 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 021 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  |
2018-07-26 15:51:57.797 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 022 Retrying couchdb request in 8s. Attempt:7  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
2018-07-26 15:52:05.774 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 023 HTTP Request: GET / HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  |
2018-07-26 15:52:05.778 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 024 Retrying couchdb request in 16s. Attempt:8  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp: lookup couchdb on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
```

I have tried `dns_search: .` in `docker-compose.yml` (did not work):

```
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$ARCH-1.1.0
    dns_search: .
```

---

UPDATE:

```
➜  fabric-dev-servers docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                                            NAMES
9609e59d9aae        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0                                                                                   "peer node start"        35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes                 0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
0a90039cf2b4        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0                                                                                "orderer"                35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes                 0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
5467fdc66163        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0                                                                                     "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   35 minutes ago      Up 35 minutes                 0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com
3cde1ba969ec        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6                                                                                "tini -- /docker-ent…"   35 minutes ago      Exited (140) 35 minutes ago                                                    couchdb

➜  fabric-dev-servers docker logs 3cde1ba969ec
****************************************************
WARNING: CouchDB is running in Admin Party mode.
         This will allow anyone with access to the
         CouchDB port to access your database. In
         Docker's default configuration, this is
         effectively any other container on the same
         system.
         Use "-e COUCHDB_USER=admin -e COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password"
         to set it in "docker run".
****************************************************
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.202791Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_log started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.208049Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application folsom started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.253376Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_stats started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.253597Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application khash started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.264200Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_event started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.267901Z nonode@nohost <0.47.0> -------- alarm_handler: {set,{{disk_almost_full,"/"},[]}}
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.267928Z nonode@nohost <0.47.0> -------- alarm_handler: {set,{{disk_almost_full,"/etc/hosts"},[]}}
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.272716Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application ibrowse started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.278981Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application ioq started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.279354Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application mochiweb started on node nonode@nohost
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.288023Z nonode@nohost <0.195.0> -------- Apache CouchDB 2.1.1 is starting.

[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.288096Z nonode@nohost <0.196.0> -------- Starting couch_sup
[notice] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.333379Z nonode@nohost <0.82.0> -------- config: [couchdb] uuid set to 5b1413abef87c0bc0b1309b45890afb4 for reason nil
[error] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.335982Z nonode@nohost <0.82.0> -------- gen_server config terminated with reason: no match of right hand value {error,enospc} at config_writer:save_to_file/2(line:38) <= config:handle_call/3(line:242) <= gen_server:try_handle_call/4(line:629) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:661) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
  last msg: {set,"couchdb","uuid","5b1413abef87c0bc0b1309b45890afb4",true,nil}
     state: {config,[],["/opt/couchdb/bin/../etc/default.ini","/opt/couchdb/bin/../etc/local.ini","/opt/couchdb/bin/../etc/local.d/local.ini"],"/opt/couchdb/bin/../etc/local.d/local.ini"}
[error] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.337953Z nonode@nohost <0.82.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process config (<0.82.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: no match of right hand value {error,enospc} at config_writer:save_to_file/2(line:38) <= config:handle_call/3(line:242) <= gen_server:try_handle_call/4(line:629) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:661) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) at gen_server:terminate/7(line:826) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {config,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [config_sup,<0.80.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.81.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 17731, stack_size: 27, reductions: 86731
[error] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.339023Z nonode@nohost <0.195.0> -------- Error starting Apache CouchDB:

    {error,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,httpd,{'EXIT',{{{badmatch,{error,enospc}},[{config_writer,save_to_file,2,[{file,"src/config_writer.erl"},{line,38}]},{config,handle_call,3,[{file,"src/config.erl"},{line,242}]},{gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,629}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,661}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]},{gen_server,call,[config,{set,"couchdb","uuid","5b1413abef87c0bc0b1309b45890afb4",true,nil},30000]}}}}}}}}


[error] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.341511Z nonode@nohost <0.81.0> -------- Supervisor config_sup had child config started with config:start_link(["/opt/couchdb/bin/../etc/default.ini","/opt/couchdb/bin/../etc/local.ini","/opt/couchdb/bin/../..."]) at <0.82.0> exit with reason no match of right hand value {error,enospc} at config_writer:save_to_file/2(line:38) <= config:handle_call/3(line:242) <= gen_server:try_handle_call/4(line:629) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:661) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.341819Z nonode@nohost <0.204.0> -------- Supervisor couch_secondary_services had child httpd started with couch_httpd:start_link() at undefined exit with reason {'EXIT',{{{badmatch,{error,enospc}},[{config_writer,save_to_file,2,[{file,"src/config_writer.erl"},{line,38}]},{config,handle_call,3,[{file,"src/config.erl"},{line,242}]},{gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,629}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,661}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]},{gen_server,call,[config,{set,"couchdb","uuid","5b1413abef87c0bc0b1309b45890afb4",true,nil},30000]}}} in context start_error
[error] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.342201Z nonode@nohost <0.196.0> -------- Supervisor couch_sup had child couch_secondary_services started with couch_secondary_sup:start_link() at undefined exit with reason {shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,httpd,{'EXIT',{{{badmatch,{error,enospc}},[{config_writer,save_to_file,2,[{file,"src/config_writer.erl"},{line,38}]},{config,handle_call,3,[{file,"src/config.erl"},{line,242}]},{gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,629}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,661}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]},{gen_server,call,[config,{set,"couchdb","uuid","5b1413abef87c0bc0b1309b45890afb4",true,nil},...]}}}}} in context start_error
[error] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.342364Z nonode@nohost <0.194.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.194.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,httpd,{'EXIT',{{{badmatch,{error,enospc}},[{config_writer,save_to_file,2,[{file,"src/config_writer.erl"},{line,38}]},{config,handle_call,3,[{file,"src/config.erl"},{line,242}]},{gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,629}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,661}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]},{gen_server,call,[config,{set,...},...]}}}}}}},...} at application_master:init/4(line:134) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2',...]}, ancestors: [<0.193.0>], messages: [{'EXIT',<0.195.0>,normal}], links: [<0.193.0>,<0.7.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 987, stack_size: 27, reductions: 152
[info] 2018-07-26T16:16:44.342640Z nonode@nohost <0.7.0> -------- Application couch exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,httpd,{'EXIT',{{{badmatch,{error,enospc}},[{config_writer,save_to_file,2,[{file,"src/config_writer.erl"},{line,38}]},{config,handle_call,3,[{file,"src/config.erl"},{line,242}]},{gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,629}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,661}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]},{gen_server,call,[config,{set,...},...]}}}}}}},...}
[os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,couch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_secondary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,httpd,{'EXIT',{{{badmatch,{error,enospc}},[{config_writer,save_to_file,2,[{file,\"src/config_writer.erl\"},{line,38}]},{config,handle_call,3,[{file,\"src/config.erl\"},{line,242}]},{gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,629}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,661}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,240}]}]},{gen_server,call,[config,{set,\"couchdb\",\"uuid\",\"5b1413abef87c0bc0b1309b45890afb4\",true,nil},30000]}}}}}}},{couch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 49:    13 User defined signal 2   su-exec couchdb "$@"
```

Comment: check if the couchDB container is up...

Comment: @yacovm It is not up and is having trouble starting. I updated my post with logs.

Comment: ok so that's the root cause - the peer crashed because it wasn't been able to connect to couchDB and then the endorser client inside the "peer channel join" command wasn't able to connect to the peer.

I'm not sure about the reason couchDB crashed but I suspect the smoking gun is:

"gen_server config terminated with reason: no match of right hand value {error,enospc} at config_writer:save_to_file"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/apache/couchdb-docker/issues/61#issuecomment-361752845

Docker volumes ran out of space, which explains why I was suddenly getting the error - CouchDB could no longer write to the file it needed. I ran `docker volume prune` and it freed up 5GB from a bunch of old projects, and everything works again.

Comment: Thanks for writing here the resolution for others to see